# Higgs and Coulomb Branches. What are they?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, moduli

On Wikipedia, there is an article on Moduli(Physics). The link is the following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_(physics) . What captures me is Higgs and Coulomb Branch. If you click the links on Wikipedia, for these you notice that there is  no article for them.  A Google search yields research papers non-suited for the novice.  What is a SIMPLE model that illustrates these concepts. Preferably written for a Physics high school student or College Freshman.Is there a video, or tutorial I can be directed to which goes over the concepts and operational steps?

1. I am interested in an operational definition (e.g  . .  A "X" is a "P" with . . . .)
2. A simple worked out example (e.g In a simple theory of "X" coupled to "Y" . . . in d dims the "K" branch is a  . . . . and here are steps that get you from "M" to  "Z")
3. I like diagrams and animations because I am an idiot ( e.g The vectors from point "l" are the  . . .)

I think I can benefit most from simple expository media, with the ideas explicitly stated. I have to confess, I don't want to read a full book.I am human. I can go over a page or two long article, but I love videos. I am aware of prerequisites to gain such understanding.

Comment: The problem is, you are gonna need to read more than two pages to understand it

Comment: The spontaneous symmetry breaking article has a picture illustrating a vacuum manifold, but for these more complicated examples in this article it is harder to picture.

Comment: The definition of the Higgs and Coulomb branch is *right there in the article*. The moduli space locally factors as the product of the moduli of a vector multiplet and a hypermultiplet, and the first factor is called the Coulomb branch and the second the Higgs branch. What exactly do you want to know about that? For the usage outside of $\mathcal{N}=2$ 4d SYM, I've asked a question about the exact meaning [here already](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292862/50583).

Comment: Indeed it says "The N=2 supersymmetry algebra contains two representations with scalars, the vector multiplet which contains a complex scalar and the hypermultiplet which contains two complex scalars."  The case of N= 2  in 4d is well known. The general meaning eludes me.  I am going to be keeping an eye on your question. I am motivated by curiosity. I am not doing research on this.

Answer (score 4):

Oh hi there . . .

Symmetry breaking happens

- You can break gauge symmetry via the higgs mechanism.  Sometimes different types of higgs fields transform differently.

  a) Coulomb phase : broken to a product of U(1) factors

  b) Higss Phase :  the breaking was so hardcore, all U(1) factors died

  Consider N =2 super Yang-Mills as @Dirac,@ACuriousMind, Wikipedia ( and perhaps me, depending on if you had coffee) have pointed out
  "The moduli space locally factors as the product of the moduli of a vector multiplet and a hypermultiplet, and the first factor is called the Coulomb branch and the second the Higgs branch" -- ACuriousMind

@Diracology also points out that this kind of thinking helps characterize the phases of super-symmetric  gauge theory.

For the full treatment ncatlab has a link of references.  Some of them might even address  @AcuriousMind's comment  about meaning outside of N = 2.

Notably
 Hiraku Nakajima, Towards a mathematical definition of Coulomb branches of 3-dimensional =4\mathcal{N} = 4 gauge theories, I (arXiv:1503.03676)

References

1.) [What's the Coulomb Branch and why is it important?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102272/whats-the-coulomb-branch-and-why-is-it-important?rq=1)

2.)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_phase

3.) [What is the relation between the representation the Higgs field transforms under, the types of couplings in the theory and Higgs/Coulomb branches?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72019/what-is-the-relation-between-the-representation-the-higgs-field-transforms-under/227379#227379)

4.) https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Coulomb+branch

5.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking